# Custom post Query and WordPress Post Query Clash

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-query, loop, page-template

I was building a custom WordPress theme, and I am facing the following issue.

If I create a page template with a custom post query and pagination, it seems to work fine and render the pagination as supposed. But if I make the page as the homepage from theme customization pagination doesn't seem to work.

How do I sort this?

Here is my code in page-template.php

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Pagebuilder + latest articles + pagination */
get_header();
?>
 <?php 
if(!empty($post->post_content)) { //show this only when we have content
    if (empty($paged) or $paged < 2) { //show this only on the first page
        if (have_posts()) { ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <div class="td-container">
                    <div class="td-container-border">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php }
    }
}
?>

    <?php   
                $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
                          'posts_per_page' =>'2',
                          'paged' => $paged
                          ));

                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();    
                ?>
                    <li class=smile>
                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    </li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php pagination( $the_query->max_num_pages ); ?>
    <?php

get_footer();
```

Here is my pagination function.

```
function pagination($pages = '', $range = 2) {  
     $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;  

     global $paged;
     if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

     if($pages == '')
     {
         global $wp_query;
         $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
         if(!$pages)
         {
             $pages = 1;
         }
     }   

     if(1 != $pages)
     {
         echo "<div class='pagination'>";
         if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo;</a>";
         if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo;</a>";

         for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
         {
             if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
             {
                 echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class='current'>".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class='inactive' >".$i."</a>";
             }
         }

         if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."'>&rsaquo;</a>";  
         if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>&raquo;</a>";
         echo "</div>\n";
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
                          'posts_per_page' =>'2',
                          'paged' => $paged
                          ));
```

Replace With this:

```
global $wp_query;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query,  array( 'posts_per_page' =>'2','paged' => $paged ) );
query_posts( $args );
```

**NOTE:** This code is not tested so first backup your page.

Comment: thanks brov, but it doesn't seem to work, same issue, pagination works fine on the pages but when page is made homepage doesn't.